# How to adjust/extend the Content Editor Web Part in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm new to Sharepoint 2013 and Visual Studio. So I'd like to build a Sharepoint 2013 add-in where the user can adjust the add-in by giving the add-in some parameters. Just like this Facebook add-in (see picture) I want to have a special set of properties besides the three default options {Appearance, Layout, Advanced}.

[it supposed to look similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYkPt.png)

I found the following article to this problem. Now my problem is that I have created a "SharePoint Add-in" project in visual studio where no .ascx.cs file is created in template.

http://www.ashokraja.me/articles/How-to-create-a-custom-property-and-set-a-default-value-in-a-SharePoint-2013-Visual-WebPart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint add-in,server side code is not allowed. If you have on-premise SharePoint 2013 then you need to change your template to visual web part.(the link you have shared this is for Visual web part). If you are working with SharePoint online then you need to make it all custom using client side scripting.